# Display special characters (circled letters) or unicode from R to Excel

Tags: r, excel, unicode

I am trying to display special characters as is when I save the data frame in excel.

```
> All_Matches_AOT$FORM1[i] <- paste(historical_result3$form, collapse = "")
[1] "ⓌWⓁⓌWⓌ"
```

However, it only saves in unicode format as per below

```
> str(All_Matches_AOT$FORM1[i])
 chr "<U+24CC>W<U+24C1><U+24CC>W<U+24CC>"
```

so, in excel it displays as

```
<U+24CC>W<U+24C1><U+24CC>W<U+24CC>
```

Is there any chance that it gets saved in special character format("ⓌWⓁⓌWⓌ") in excel when I roll over R data frame into excel?

Comment: what excel library in R are you using? I cannot reproduce your issue with `xlsx::` also not with `openxlsx::`.

Comment: I would prefer xlsx but any library is fine i guess.. how about csv?